# C Programming - Pointer Adress Byte Split

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following variable var which is an unsigned 32bit value.
I am working on a little endian system.

```
unsigned long var = 1;
// Representation: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

Now I want to access the first and the last 16 bit via:

```
(((unsigned short*)&var)[0])) => 00000000 00000001

(((unsigned short*)&var)[1])) => 00000000 00000000
```

Is there any C documentation for this type of pointer adress type split?
I got this working but I do not know how this works.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming a `short` is 16-bit, essentially the code is treating `var` as if it is in the same memory location as an array of two `short`.

Comment: Better to use `uint16_t` and `#include <stdint.h>`.

Comment: @MitchWheat No, there's documentation of why this doesn't work. Undefined behavior per C11 6.5/7.

Comment: @Lundin is correct. Don't do that. There is plenty of documentation explaining why you shouldn't.

Comment: just looked can't find it: could you quote the text please (or portion of it). I thought that only applied to non strictly aligned types?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: @MitchWheat I posted an answer below.

Comment: This is undefined behavior.  If you want to access a block of memory as different types, use a union.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you can access any data type in C through a pointer to character type, such as `unsigned char*` or `uint8_t*`. If you cast `var` to such a character pointer, you get a pointer to the first byte:

```
unsigned char* cptr = (unsigned char*)&var;
```

You can then reference that pointer to get the contents, either by doing `*cptr` or `cptr[0]` - this means the same thing. On a little endian system you now have a pointer to the least significant byte. `cptr[1]` will give the byte after that, and so on.

*However* this is *only* guaranteed to work for character types! No other type like `unsigned short` can be used - that would give a so called "strict aliasing violation". [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) Meaning that if you have code like this:

```
unsigned long var = 1;
*(unsigned short*)&var = 123;
if(var == 1)
  printf("Look mom, I violated strict aliasing!");
```

Then the compiler is free to generate code that executes the printf statement. Or it can also change `var` just like you expect and don't execute printf. Or it can crash and burn: it is undefined behavior, anything can happen. Bugs like this are frequent to appear on the gcc compiler in particular, with high optimization enabled.